# semi-logarithmic in python,

Tags: python, curve-fitting, logarithm

I am doing medical image analysis and I want to apply this equation to do mono-exponential fitting for my dataset.

```
x = log(Sb/S0) / -b
```

***In summary, I have 3 possible values to Sb according to b and I want find a suitable fit for that. For example if Sb = [5,3.5,1.3] for b = [300,600,1000], How should I proceed given that my real data is more complex than that.***

x is the parametric map representing the signal decay in the acquired diffusion images Sb. S0 is the baseline image with no diffusion gradient applied.

It is possible to calculate x using two points only. But fitting it to multiple points eliminate the possible effect of noise and is generally more accurate.

I have Sb1000, Sb600, Sb300 and I want to fit x for each of the three variants of the equation.

My initial guess is that I should use `curve_fit` but I am not sure how should I place my variables.

My variables are:

```
Sb = Numpy 3D array (38,240,240) -- 3 Different sets Sb100, Sb600, Sb300

S0 = Numpy 3D array (38,240,240)
```

b is an integer

I have tried also `Numpy.linalg.solve()` with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Hey. What's Sb and b?

Comment: I am doing MRI diffusion image analysis to build a parametric map called (ADC). Anyway, I have 3 different Diffusion images (Sb variable) and I use the above mentioned equation to obtain the ADC (X). Currently, I can produce three maps by placing a a different Sb array each time.

Comment: It is supposed to provide more accurate estimation of X if I included more than b value in my analysis. The image signal decay is linear but to eliminate the effect of noise, fitting the curve on more than two points is preferred.

Comment: is `(38,240,240)` a tuple of 3 values or the shape of `Sb` and `S0` ?

Comment: this is the shape of the arrays

Comment: What data does your dataset contain? Is it `S0`?

Comment: Sb and S0 are arrays of the same image set but with different diffusion weighting and in order to produce a parametric map, we use map = log(Sb/S0) / -b, It can be done voxel by voxel or using the whole array as in my case. I want to include the 3 measured Sb values in the equation where x is fitted to them instead of a single value

Comment: So Sb or S0 are stack of 38 images each is 240 X 240 pixel